# Is this the case of method hiding?

Tags: java, overriding, method-hiding

i have following code in which the base class Employee have a static method meth1() which i am able to call from a child class (Pro) object . Is it a case of method hiding or what ? , i am not sure because i haven't implemented the meth1() method in Pro class, but still able to call Emplyee static method from Pro object.

```
class Employee
{  

  String s;

    public String getS() {
        return s;
    }

    public void setS(String s) {
        this.s = s;
    }
    protected static void meth1()
    {
        System.out.println("inside emp-meth1");
    }

}
public class Pro extends Employee {
/*
 *  public void meth1()
    {
        System.out.println("inside encapsulation-meth1");
    }
    */
    public static void main(String as[])
    {
        Pro e = new Pro();
    //  e.s ="jay";
        e.meth1();

    }

}
```

Output:

```
inside emp-meth1
```

Thanks

Jayendra

Comment: What do you think you've hidden?

Comment: You have meth1() in Pro commented out.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you are asking?

Comment: That's not hiding. Your attempt won't even compile because `Employee#meth1` is `static` and you cannot override `static` methods.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza [Hiding does apply to methods.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.8.2)

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis oh right, you cannot override `static` methods because you hide them. Duh! for me :)

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis so why is it able to call the method meth1() which is in the base class . why is it happening . Shouldn't it throw an error as static methods are not inherited. please correct me if am wrong

Comment: @jayendrabhatt Non private methods are inherited, even `static` ones.

Comment: Sotirios Delimanolis ohh got it .that means static methods can be inherited if they are non private and they cant be overriden but can be be hidden .

Answer (score 1):

What are you trying to hide?
Try the below code

`emp.meth1()` will call method based on reference not based on the object being referred.

```
class Employee
{  

  String s;

public String getS() {
    return s;
}

public void setS(String s) {
    this.s = s;
}
protected static void meth1()
{
    System.out.println("inside emp-meth1");
   }

}
public class Pro extends Employee {
  protected static void meth1()
  {
    System.out.println("inside encapsulation-meth1");
  }

public static void main(String as[])
{
    Pro e = new Pro();
    Employee emp = new Pro();
    emp.meth1();       //this is case of method hiding 
    e.meth1();

}
```

}

Comment: thats what am asking , why the above code (the one at the top) is working . The static method is not inherited by the subclass then how is it able to call the meth1() in the parent class?